# How to display ActiveAdmin menu tabs in the dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have too many models in my rails app. And they don't fit in the top menu bar in active admin.

I would like to know how to display the top menu tabs, in a vertical menu via the dashboard?

Thanks in advance.

Eg:

- Model 1
- Model 2
- Model 3
- ...

[image: Active Admin]

**Dashboard.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div :class => "blank_slate_container", :id => "dashboard_default_message" do
      span :class => "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end

    # Here is an example of a simple dashboard with columns and panels.
    #
    # columns do
    #   column do
    #     panel "Recent Posts" do
    #       ul do
    #         Post.recent(5).map do |post|
    #           li link_to(post.title, admin_post_path(post))
    #         end
    #       end
    #     end
    #   end

    #   column do
    #     panel "Info" do
    #       para "Welcome to ActiveAdmin."
    #     end
    #   end
    # end
  end # content
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:parent` option to the `menu` method to assign each model into a menu drop down in each model's admin file.

So:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu :parent => "User Data"
end
```

If you want to create a list of links on the dashboard page, your code would look something like this:

```
  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    columns do
      column do
        panel "Models" do
          ul do
            li link_to("Users", admin_users_path)
            li link_to("Admin Users", admin_admin_users_path)
          end
        end
      end
   end
```